# Hosting Virtual Directory with Nancy on IIS

Tags: iis-7, nancy

I have a NancyFx application where I've setup an Virtual Directory under the path `/photos`. However, when I browse to it I get a 404. I have made sure permissions etc.. are correct so I'm wondering if it is something to do with NancyFx hijacking the request and looking for a route defined under my `/photos` path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to tell IIS to not use Nancy in the /photo directory. You can do this by adding the location in your web.config like so:

```
<location path="photo">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="Nancy"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content#letting-iis-handle-static-content